# Efficient coding: Push pattern instead of pull

Tags: java, c#, .net, architecture, bigdata

Consider value of x keeps changing every second.

I need to monitor x every second and do a task when it crosss a specific value.

One way to deal with this is to use IF statement and compare the value every second.

However in my case this gets triggered only once every 4-5 hours but we dont know which Second it triggers within this 4-5hour period.

Question

Instead of wasting huge amount of processing power and comparing every second using an IF block. 
Is there any other alternative where i can stay idle most of the period and expect the code to notify or trigger an event only when this happens? I.e staying idle for 4-5hours except the one second where the value reaches a desired number.

Comment: Listen for an event, raise an event to cause the data change?

Comment: Well does the trigger raise an Event?   You just add an Event Handler.

Comment: If this is .NET have you considered `Reactive Extensions`?

Comment: Events and observer pattern if i am not wrong still requires an IF block within the add method or set property where i need to check if x is greater than a value. This means every second i am still using cpu. I am looking to keep my cpu idle until the value croses a given number.

Comment: Checking every second, while not the best  solution, won't waste 'huge amount of computing power'.

Comment: @Tymek Well probably you are right in some cases. But in my case i need to run this against thousands of threads in parallel. Thats where CPU would go nuts even though nothing much is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [observer design pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html), this should fit your needs

Your changing value service (or whatever it is) should provide an option to register a listener, and then raise an event to notify all listener whenever the value changes

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case i dont have multiple observers. There would be a single observer and a single subject. Can i still use this to push notify me when say a variable crosses a specific value. ?

Comment: @Skiran yeap, no issue with one listener only

Comment: Thanks. Looks like i will still need an IF block to check if its greater than a value. Ideally this stays in the set method within property and therefore gets executed every second utilising CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) in case you need to deal with client server like setup.